# Comparing (varchar, nvarchar2,varchar2) with QString

Tags: c++, oracle, qt, stored-procedures

I have problem while comparing varchar,nvarchar2 or varchar2 with QString variable that I pass to Oracle database.

```
 CREATE TABLE Korisnici
        (
            id_korisnika varchar(200) PRIMARY KEY,
            ime_korisnika varchar2(200),
            prezime_korisnika varchar2(200),
            broj_telefona varchar2(30),
            adresa_korisnika varchar2(400)
        )
        /
```

and here is my procedure:

```
//procedure for updating user
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Update_korisnika(
        stari_id IN varchar,
        novo_ime_korisnika IN varchar2,
        novo_prezime_korisnika IN varchar2,
        novi_broj_telefona_korisnika IN varchar2,
        nova_adresa_korisnika IN varchar2)

    IS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Korisnici 
        SET Korisnici.ime_korisnika=novo_ime_korisnika
            , Korisnici.prezime_korisnika=novo_prezime_korisnika
            , Korisnici.broj_telefona=novi_broj_telefona_korisnika
            , Korisnici.adresa_korisnika=nova_adresa_korisnika 
        WHERE Korisnici.id_korisnika=stari_id;
        COMMIT;
   END;
   /
```

And qt code from which I send char when debugging:

```
//this is for updateing user
    void MainWindow::promjeni_korisnika(const QString& id, const QString& ime, const QString& prezime, const QString& broj, const QString& adresa)
    {
        //parametri
        init();
        QUrl params;
            params.addQueryItem("action","Update_korisnika");
            params.addQueryItem("id",id);
            params.addQueryItem("ime",ime);
            params.addQueryItem("prezime",prezime);
            params.addQueryItem("broj",broj);
            params.addQueryItem("adresa",adresa);

            QByteArray data;
            data.append(params.toString());
            data.remove(0,1);

            QNetworkRequest request;
            request.setUrl(url);
            request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,
            QVariant("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

            manager->post(request, data);

            MainWindow::dataList.clear();
            Citanje_korisnika();
    }
```

So I only have problem with procedures which use ID, how to make this all work. What type of data should this ID be that can be compared so I can use it.

EDIT:
this is QML function which sends data to QT function above:

```
 funkcije.promjeni_korisnika(text_input5.text,text_input1.text,text_input2.text,text_input3.text,text_input4.text);
```

then this part of script accepts data:

```
Update_korisnika($poslani_ar,$id=$_POST['id_korisnika'],$ime=$_POST['ime'],$prezime=$_POST['prezime'],$broj=$_POST['broj'],$adresa=$_POST['adresa']);
```

and then this part calls this code :

```
function Update_korisnika($poslani_ar,$id,$ime,$prezime,$broj,$adresa)
{
    $imenik = new Imenik($poslani_ar,$id,$ime,$prezime,$broj,$adresa);
    $imenik->Update_korisnika();
}
```

then:

```
function Update_korisnika(){
        $query='BEGIN Update_korisnika(:id_korisnika,:ime_korisnika,:prezime_korisnika,:broj_telefona,:adresa);END;';
        $result=$this->connector->Exec($this->poslani_argument,$query,$this->id_korisnika,$this->ime_korisnika,$this->prezime_korisnika,$this->broj_telefona,$this->adresa);
        //echo $ArrayToXml->toXml($result);
    }
```

and at the end have only script that execute all things. I didn't put any constructors and unnecessary stuff. This is a part of code that for example work together.

How can I trace it when PHP is triggered.

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem?  If the problem is that the stored procedure is not updating any data, can you log `stari_id` that is being passed in?  What is the `stari_id` that is passed in and what is the `id_korisnika` of the row that you expect to be updated?  Are there spaces at the end of one and not the other or are there differences in casing?

Comment: Problem is when I want to add item I can make it normaly. But when I want to update for example change data. I need to use old_id(stari_id) which I send from QT code as Qstring id and nothing happens. Between QT and oracle I have php script which handleds data but script is working fine. oracle and QT has some problem in casting. When I post data to oracle I debug it and I can see that I am sending for example id_user(id_korisnika) as '3'. But nothing is updateing

Comment: 1) If `id_korisnika` is a number, it really ought to be defined as a `NUMBER` in the database rather than as a string.  2) Are you stating that you have logging in the stored procedure that indicates that the `STARI_ID` that is being passed in is the string '3' with no leading or trailing spaces and that you can query the `Korisnici` table and see a row with an `id_korisnika` of '3' and that the `UPDATE` statement is updating no rows?

Comment: at the begining id_korisnika was as number, then I tried to change it as varchar,nvarchar2,varchar2. But there is some kind of problem. I don't know how to trace it in stored procedure. When calling select * from Korisnici in SQL plus I can see number 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by logging what is being sent to the stored procedure.  If you modify the stored procedure to log the data being passed in and the number of rows updated, what do you see?

```
CREATE TABLE update_proc_log (
  id_korisnika varchar2(200),
  ime_korisnika varchar2(200),
  prezime_korisnika varchar2(200),
  broj_telefona varchar2(30),
  adresa_korisnika varchar2(400),
  rows_updated     number,
  call_timestamp   timestamp
);



CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Update_korisnika(
    stari_id IN varchar,
    novo_ime_korisnika IN varchar2,
    novo_prezime_korisnika IN varchar2,
    novi_broj_telefona_korisnika IN varchar2,
    nova_adresa_korisnika IN varchar2)

IS
  l_rows_updated integer;
BEGIN
    UPDATE Korisnici 
    SET Korisnici.ime_korisnika=novo_ime_korisnika
        , Korisnici.prezime_korisnika=novo_prezime_korisnika
        , Korisnici.broj_telefona=novi_broj_telefona_korisnika
        , Korisnici.adresa_korisnika=nova_adresa_korisnika 
    WHERE Korisnici.id_korisnika=stari_id;
    l_rows_updated := sql%rowcount;

    INSERT INTO update_proc_log( id_korisnika ,
                                 ime_korisnika ,
                                 prezime_korisnika ,
                                 broj_telefona ,
                                 adresa_korisnika ,
                                 rows_updated ,
                                 call_timestamp )
      VALUES( stari_id,
              novo_ime_korisnika,
              novo_prezime_korisnika,
              novi_broj_telefona_korisnika,
              nova_adresa_korisnika ,
              l_rows_updated,
              systimestamp );
    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: ID is not displayed. but I can see that for example name is changed. But id is empty space.

Comment: @denonth - ID is not displayed where?  In the log table?  Is there a row in the log table?  What is `ROWS_UPDATED` set to in the log table?

Comment: @denonth - OK.  So, then, are you stating that the `stari_id` value that is being passed in is NULL?  That would certainly explain why no rows are being updated.  If the PHP script is calling the stored procedure, that implies that the PHP script is not passing the correct `stari_id` to Oracle.  You'd need to do a similar debugging effort in PHP to figure out whether that is because PHP is not getting the proper value from Qt or whether the PHP script has a bug.  Since you haven't posted the PHP script, it's hard to know what the problem might be.

Comment: honestly I don't know how to debug in php when script is triggered. So I will edit my question with all code that is working together.

Comment: @denonth - Just like we did with the stored procedure, modify the PHP script to log the data that is passed to it.  You need to track down why the `stari_id` value is not being passed to Oracle.

Comment: Ok I'll try. I'll mark it as answer because you really helped me

Answer (score 2):

> "at the begining id_korisnika was as number, then I tried to change it
>   as varchar,nvarchar2,varchar2. But there is some kind of problem. I
>   don't know how to trace it in stored procedure. When calling select *
>   from Korisnici in SQL plus I can see number 3."

Okay, so your actual problem is that you are storing a number in a string datatype.  It may look like `3` in a query but it could be `' 3'` , `'3 '`, `' 3 '`, `'3'` or any other permutation of three and space.

So, just sort out your data model.